# 100 Vm's are suddenly stopped in my Azure portal

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

in my azure portal suddenly 100 vm 's are stopped all are in same region and subscription..please help me ..

am getting below error

Failed to start virtual machine Failed to start the virtual machines

Comment: I suspect you run out of credits

Answer (score 0):

Which region you are facing this issue? And you can also check whether your virtual machines are under planned maintenance experience?

Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/a-new-planned-maintenance-experience-for-your-virtual-machines/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-friday-virtual-machine-planned-maintenance-rafalovich/

You can refer the following about planned maintenance:

•   Planned maintenance how-to guide and FAQs for [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/maintenance-notifications) or [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/maintenance-notifications) VMs.

•   Information about [types of maintenance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/maintenance-and-updates) performed on VMs.

•   Using Azure Monitor for [activity logs and alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-alerts).